# functions stops working after calling another function with onload event in

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript rollover routine (admittedly rather old, but it still works, apart from this one problem) that when you click the last button (b8) it does a setTimeout call to an image preLoad function that has multiple onload events that call another function that then ends when all the images have been loaded and then makes multiple setInterval calls to start an animation. This is working fine, but the function (click) where the original setTimeout call is made does not complete and call the subsequent (off) function and also subsequent event calls (onclick and mouseover) from the html code do not work; although the pages still load the rollover does not work any more.

I have done a bit of research into it and it seems to be the onload event that seems to be messing it up because, if I call another function (say positionlayers) it works as intended, but obviously doesn't preload the images and consequently some are missing from the animation. I have tried creating an onlcik event for the image rather than using href="javascript:click('b8')", but the page isn't loading. I have tried a clearTimeout in the preLoad function, but no change; the click function breaks again, even though the page is loaded and the animation plays. I have also tried a number of other things which I cannot now remember, but didn't work

The expected result is that the function (click) should finish and animate the button up graphic, called by the off function instead of breaking

EDIT

Here's the complete javascript code(with the exception of the html code in the javascript for clientshtml etc, that is used for the other buttons):

```
shuttlehtml='<div id="cv">';
shuttlehtml+='<DIV ID="msgLyr" STYLE="position:absolute;left: 12px; top: 9px; width: 300px; height: 200px; z-index: 9; visibility: visible;">';
shuttlehtml+='<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=300><TR>'; 
shuttlehtml+='<TD BGCOLOR=#800000><FONT class="status">Loading Page...</FONT></TD></TR>';
shuttlehtml+='</TABLE></DIV>';
shuttlehtml+='<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="shuttle"><tr><td height="33%" valign="top" align="right"><img src="luna.gif" border="0"></td></tr><tr><td height="33%"><img src="mountain.gif" width="100%" height="165" border="0"></td></tr><tr><td td bgcolor="#023b06" height="30%"><img src="trans.gif" height="100" /></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor="#023b06" height="58"><center><img src="platform.gif" border="0" /></center></td></tr></table>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="bodwing" style="position:absolute;width:200px; height:115px; z-index:2; left: 439px; top: -154px; visibility: hidden"><img src="bodyshell2.gif" width="198" height="305" name="bodywing"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="rwing" style="position:absolute;width:200px; height:115px; z-index:1; left: 598px; top: -115px; visibility: hidden"><img src="rwing1.gif" width="275" height="395" id="rwing1"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="lwing" style="position:absolute;width:200px; height:115px; z-index:1; left: 207px; top: -115px; visibility: hidden"><img src="lwing1.gif" width="275" height="395" id="lwing1"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="rleg" style="position:absolute;width:50px; height:58px; z-index:1; left: 535px; top: 86px; visibility: hidden"><img src="rleg.gif" width="50" height="58" name="rightleg"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="head" style="position:absolute;width:78px; height:99px; z-index:4; left: 500px; top: 77px; visibility: hidden"><img src="head1.gif" width="78" height="99" name="head1"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="lflap" style="position:absolute;width:38px; height:30px; left: 460px; top: 143px; z-index: 3; visibility: hidden"><img src="noflap.gif" width="38" height="30" name="leftflap"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="rflap" style="position:absolute;width:38px; height:30px; z-index:3; left: 579px; top: 144px; visibility: hidden"><img src="noflap.gif" width="38" height="30" name="rightflap"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='<div id="lleg" style="position:absolute;width:50px; height:58px; z-index:1; left: 492px; top: 86px; visibility: hidden"><img src="lleg.gif" width="50" height="58" name="leftleg"></div>';
shuttlehtml+='</div>';

buttonhtml='<table class="table2"><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td colspan=3><img src="topmenu.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b1" href="javascript:click(\'b1\')" onmouseover="on(\'b1\');window.status=\'Go back to the ONE WORLD home Page\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="homea.gif" ALT="" name="b1"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b2" href="javascript:click(\'b2\')" onmouseover="on(\'b2\');window.status=\'Hints & tips on web browsing.\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="helpa.gif" ALT="" name="b2"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b3" href="javascript:click(\'b3\')" onmouseover="on(\'b3\');window.status=\'Use our comprehensive list of search engines to search the World Wide Web\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="searcha.gif" ALT="" name="b3"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b4" href="javascript:click(\'b4\')" onmouseover="on(\'b4\');window.status=\'Download the latest browsers & help on making ONE WORLD your home page\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="setupa.gif" ALT=""  name="b4"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b5" href="javascript:click(\'b5\')" onmouseover="on(\'b5\');window.status=\'View our comprehensive list of FREE email providers\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="emaila.gif" ALT=""  name="b5"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b6" href="javascript:click(\'b6\')" onmouseover="on(\'b6\');window.status=\'View my CV as well as details about the site itself\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="abouta.gif" ALT=""  name="b6"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b7" href="javascript:click(\'b7\')" onmouseover="on(\'b7\');window.status=\'See my portfolio of clients\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="clientsa.gif" ALT=""  name="b7"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr><tr>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butlside.gif" ALT=""></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><a name="b8" href="javascript:click(\'b8\')" onmouseover="on(\'b8\');window.status=\'See creative projects I have done\';return true" onmouseout="off();window.status=\'\';return true"><img src="projectsa.gif" ALT="" name="b8"></a></td>';
buttonhtml+='<td><img src="butrside.gif" ALT=""></td></tr></table><img src="butbott.gif" align="top" ALT="">';

 counter = 0;
moving = 0;
winganim=0;
leganim=0;
flapanim=0;

function preLoad() {
    pics= new Array();
    pics[0]=new Image();
    pics[0].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[0].src="rwing1.gif";
    pics[1]=new Image();
    pics[1].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[1].src="rwing2.gif";
    pics[2]=new Image();
    pics[2].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[2].src="rwing3.gif";
    pics[3]=new Image();
    pics[3].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[3].src="rwing4.gif";
    pics[4]=new Image();
    pics[4].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[4].src="rwing5.gif";
    pics[5]=new Image();
    pics[5].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[5].src="rwing6.gif";
    pics[6]=new Image();
    pics[6].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[6].src="rwing7.gif";
    pics[7]=new Image();
    pics[7].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[7].src="rwing8.gif";
    pics[8]=new Image();
    pics[8].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[8].src="rwing9.gif";
    pics[9]=new Image();
    pics[9].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[9].src="rwing10.gif";
    pics[10]=new Image();
    pics[10].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[10].src="rwing11.gif";
    pics[11]=new Image();
    pics[11].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[11].src="rwing12.gif";
    pics[12]=new Image();
    pics[12].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[12].src="rwing13.gif";
    pics[13]=new Image();
    pics[13].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[13].src="rwing14.gif";
    pics[14]=new Image();
    pics[14].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[14].src="lwing1.gif";
    pics[15]=new Image();
    pics[15].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[15].src="lwing2.gif";
    pics[16]=new Image();
    pics[16].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[16].src="lwing3.gif";
    pics[17]=new Image();
    pics[17].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[17].src="lwing4.gif";
    pics[18]=new Image();
    pics[18].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[18].src="lwing5.gif";
    pics[19]=new Image();
    pics[19].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[19].src="lwing6.gif";
    pics[20]=new Image();
    pics[20].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[20].src="lwing7.gif";
    pics[21]=new Image();
    pics[21].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[21].src="lwing8.gif";
    pics[22]=new Image();
    pics[22].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[22].src="lwing9.gif";
    pics[23]=new Image();
    pics[23].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[23].src="lwing10.gif";
    pics[24]=new Image();
    pics[24].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[24].src="lwing11.gif";
    pics[25]=new Image();
    pics[25].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[25].src="lwing12.gif";
    pics[26]=new Image();
    pics[26].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[26].src="lwing13.gif";
    pics[27]=new Image();
    pics[27].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[27].src="lwing14.gif";
    pics[28]=new Image();
    pics[28].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[28].src="noflap.gif";
    pics[29]=new Image();
    pics[29].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[29].src="lflap1.gif";
    pics[30]=new Image();
    pics[30].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[30].src="lflap2.gif";
    pics[31]=new Image();
    pics[31].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[31].src="lflap3.gif";
    pics[32]=new Image();
    pics[32].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[32].src="lflap4.gif";
    pics[33]=new Image();
    pics[33].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[33].src="lflap5.gif";
    pics[34]=new Image();
    pics[34].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[34].src="lflap6.gif";
    pics[35]=new Image();
    pics[35].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[35].src="rflap1.gif";
    pics[36]=new Image();
    pics[36].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[36].src="rflap2.gif";
    pics[37]=new Image();
    pics[37].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[37].src="rflap3.gif";
    pics[38]=new Image();
    pics[38].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[38].src="rflap4.gif";
    pics[39]=new Image();
    pics[39].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[39].src="rflap5.gif";
    pics[40]=new Image();
    pics[40].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[40].src="rflap6.gif";
    pics[41]=new Image();
    pics[41].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[41].src="bodyshell2.gif";
    pics[42]=new Image();
    pics[42].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[42].src="head1.gif";
    pics[43]=new Image();
    pics[43].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[43].src="head2.gif";
    pics[44]=new Image();
    pics[44].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[44].src="head3.gif";
    pics[45]=new Image();
    pics[45].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[45].src="head4.gif";
    pics[46]=new Image();
    pics[46].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[46].src="head5.gif";
    pics[47]=new Image();
    pics[47].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[47].src="rleg.gif";
    pics[48]=new Image();
    pics[48].onload = loadCheck;
    pics[48].src="lleg.gif";
}

function loadCheck() {
    counter++;
    if(counter == 49) {
            document.getElementById("msgLyr").style.visibility="hidden";
                    counter=0;
        t5=setTimeout("positionlayers()",0);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("msgLyr").innerHTML='<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=300><TR><TD WIDTH=' + Math.round((counter/49)*100) + '% BGCOLOR=#FF0000 ALIGN=RIGHT>' + '<FONT class="status">' + Math.round((counter/49)*100) + '%</FONT>' +'</TD><TD BGCOLOR=#800000 VALIGN=MIDDLE> </TD></TR><TR><TD COLSPAN=2 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT class="main">Percent Images Loaded</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>';
    }
}

function positionlayers() {
document.getElementById("bodwing").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("rwing").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("lwing").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("rleg").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("head").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("lflap").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("rflap").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("lleg").style.visibility = "visible";
t1=setInterval("move()",10);
t2=setInterval("wings()",200);
t3=setInterval("legs()",50);
t4=setInterval("flaps()",100);
}

function move() {
moving++;
document.getElementById("bodwing").style.top = moving-154+"px";
document.getElementById("rwing").style.top = moving-115+"px";
document.getElementById("lwing").style.top = moving-115+"px";
//document.getElementById("rleg").style.top = moving+86+"px";
document.getElementById("head").style.top = moving+77+"px";
document.getElementById("lflap").style.top = moving+143+"px";
document.getElementById("rflap").style.top = moving+143+"px";
//document.getElementById("lleg").style.top = moving+86+"px";
if (moving>350) {
clearInterval(t1);
moving=0;
}
}

function wings() {
if (winganim!=14) {
rwing1.src=pics[winganim].src;
lwing1.src=pics[winganim+14].src;
winganim++;
} else {
clearInterval(t2);
winganim=0;
}
}

function legs() {
if (leganim<70){
document.getElementById("lleg").style.top = moving+leganim+86+"px";
document.getElementById("rleg").style.top = moving+leganim+86+"px";
document.getElementById("rleg").style.left = 535+leganim+"px";
document.getElementById("lleg").style.left = 492-leganim+"px";
leganim++;
} else {
clearInterval(t3);
leganim=0;
}
}

function flaps() {
if (flapanim!=6) {
leftflap.src=pics[flapanim+29].src;
rightflap.src=pics[flapanim+35].src;
flapanim++;
} else {
clearInterval(t4);
flapanim=0;
}
}

bV=parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
browser=false;
ie3=false;
ie4=false;
ns4=false;
if(navigator.appName=="Netscape"){
  if(bV>=4){
    browser=true;ns4=true;
    }
  }
if(navigator.appName!="Netscape"){
  if (bV>=4){
    ie4=true;
    browser=true;
    }
  else if (bV==3){
    ie3=true;
    }
  }
    pics=new Array();
    oC=0;
    sCo=0;
    function bpreload(n,f){
      if(browser){
        pics[oC]=new Array(4);
        pics[oC][0]=new Image();
        pics[oC][0].src=f+"a.gif";
        pics[oC][1]=new Image();
        pics[oC][1].src=f+"b.gif";
        pics[oC][2]=new Image();
        pics[oC][2].src=f+"c.gif";
        pics[oC][3]=n;oC++;
        }
      }
      function on(co){
        if(browser){
          for(var i=0;i<=oC;i++){
            if(pics[i][3]==co){
              document.images[pics[i][3]].src=pics[i][1].src;
              sCo=i;
              i=oC;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      function off(){
        if(browser){
          document.images[pics[sCo][3]].src=pics[sCo][0].src;
                }
        }
      function click(co){
        window.status='';
        if(co=='b1'){
          location.reload();
                }
        if(co=='b2'){
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#000099";
          document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=helphtml;
          }
        if(co=='b3'){
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#000099";
          document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=searchhtml;
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.height=window.innerHeight-200+"px";
          }
        if(co=='b4'){
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#000099";
          document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=setuphtml;
          }
        if(co=='b5'){
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#000099";
          document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=emailhtml;
          }
        if(co=='b6'){
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
          document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=cvhtml;
          }
        if(co=='b7'){
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#000099";
                document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=clientshtml;
            }
        if(co=='b8'){
                    if (moving==0) {
                    document.getElementById("welcome").style.backgroundColor="#000099";
                    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=shuttlehtml;
                    t6=setTimeout("preLoad()",0);
                    }
                    }
                    if(browser){
          for(var i=0;i<=oC;i++){
            if(pics[i][3]==co){
              if(navigator.appName!="Netscape"){
                document.anchors(pics[i][3]).blur();
                }
              document.images[pics[i][3]].src=pics[i][2].src;
                            var t10=setTimeout('off()',700);
              sCo=i;
              i=oC;
              }
            }
          }

        }
        bpreload("b1","home");
        bpreload("b2","help");
        bpreload("b3","search");
        bpreload("b4","setup");
        bpreload("b5","email");
        bpreload("b6","about");
        bpreload("b7","clients");
        bpreload("b8","projects");

function setwelcomeheight (){
        document.getElementById("welcome").style.height=window.innerHeight-200+"px";
    }

function jumpbox (list) {
    document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML=buttonhtml;
    switch(list.options[list.selectedIndex].value) {
        case "danish":   
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Danish Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fdanish.gif'><i>[Danish]</i>";
        break;
        case "dutch":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Dutch Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fdutch.gif'><i>[Dutch]</i>";
        break;
        case "english":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = englishhtml;
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fenglish.gif'><i>[English]</i>";
        break;
        case "finnish":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Finnish Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='ffinnish.gif'><i>[Finnish]</i>";
        break;
        case "french":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>French Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='ffrench.gif'><i>[French]</i>";
        break;
        case "german":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>German Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fgerman.gif'><i>[German]</i>";
        break;
        case "greek":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Greek Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fgreek.gif'><i>[Greek]</i>";
        break;
        case "hungarian":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Hungarian Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fhungari.gif'><i>[Hungarian]</i>";
        break;
        case "italian":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Italian Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fitalian.gif'><i>[Italian]</i>";
        break;
        case "norwegian":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Norwegian Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fnorwegi.gif'><i>[Norwegian]</i>";
        break;
        case "polish":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Polish Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fpolish.gif'><i>[Polish]</i>";
        break;
        case "portugeuse":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Portugeuse Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fportuge.gif'><i>[Portugeuse]</i>";
        break;
        case "romanian":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Romainian Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fromania.gif'><i>[Romanian]</i>";
        break;
        case "spanish":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Spanish Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fspanish.gif'><i>[Spanish]</i>";
        break;
        case "swedish":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Swedish Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fswedish.gif'><i>[Swedish]</i>";
        break;
        case "swiss":
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<h1>Swiss Frontpage<h1>";
        document.getElementById("world").innerHTML ="<img src='fswiss.gif'><i>[Swiss]</i>";
        break;
        default:
        break;
        }
    }
```

...and the html code:

```html
<body onload="setwelcomeheight();" onresize="setwelcomeheight();">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdearth" id="world">
            <img class="earth" src="earth.gif" alt="world">
        </td>
        <td class="tdfam">
            <img src="famfrien.gif" alt="Family Friendly Site :)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img class="logo" src="logo.gif" alt="One World!">
        </td>
        <td class="tdemail">
            <a href="mailto:severindouble@gmail.com"><img src="email.gif" alt="email:severindouble@gmail.com"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr rowspan="4">
        <td class="tdearth">
        </td>
    <td class="border">
    </td>
    <td class="toprim">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdearth" id="buttons">
            </td>
        <td class="leftrim">
        </td>
        <td class="welcome" id="welcome">
        &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdearth">

        </td>
        <td class="bottomleftcorner">
        </td>
        <td class="bottomrim">

        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
<div class="center2">Welcome</div>
<div class="center2">First of all, please select your preferred viewing language</div>
<div class="center2">
    <form>
        <select>

        <option value="danish">Danish
        <option value="dutch">Dutch
        <option value="english">English
        <option value="finnish">Finnish
        <option value="french">French
        <option value="german">German
        <option value="greek">Greek
        <option value="hungarian">Hungarian
        <option value="italian">Italian
        <option value="norwegian">Norwegian
        <option value="polish">Polish
        <option value="portugeuse">Portugeuse
        <option value="romanian">Romanian
        <option value="spanish">Spanish
        <option value="swedish">Swedish
        <option value="swiss">Swiss

        </select>

        <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="jumpbox(this.form.elements[0])">

        </form>
        </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

...and the css code

```css
    #cv {overflow:auto;}
    #personal {visibility:hidden;height:0px;}
    #key {visibility: hidden;height:0px;}
    #career {visibility: hidden;height:0px;}
    #employ {visibility: hidden;height:0px;}
    #qual {visibility: hidden;height:0px;}
    #active {visibility: hidden;height:0px;}
    #referee {visibility: hidden;height:0px;}
    .h1textcolor:link {color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
    .h1textcolor:visited {color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
    .h1textcolor:active {color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
    .h1textcolor:hover {color:#000099;text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
    .table3 {width:75%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
.table4 {width:50%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;border-spacing: 2px;border-collapse:separate;}
.table5 {width:100%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;border-spacing: 2px;border-collapse:separate;}
h3 {text-align: center}
.tdbgcol2{background-color:#00dddd;color:black;}
.tdbgcol3{background-color: #00aaaa}
.tdbgcol4{background-color:#00dddd;color:black;width:25%;vertical-align: top;}
.tdbgcol5{background-color: #00aaaa;width:75%;color:black;}
.tdcv1{color:black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align: center;}
.tdcv2{color:#000099;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align: center;}
.tdcv3 {color:black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align:right;vertical-align: top;}
.tdcv4 {color:black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;}
.tdcv5 {color:black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;}

    i {text-align: center;}
    h1 {text-align: center;}
.left {float:left}
.right {float:right}
.center {display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.detailstext1:link {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.detailstext1:visited {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.detailstext1:active  {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.detailstext1:hover {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}

.detailstext2:link {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.detailstext2:visited {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.detailstext2:active  {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.detailstext2:hover {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:underline;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}

.detailstext3:link {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;vertical-align:top;}
.detailstext3:visited {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;vertical-align:top;}
.detailstext3:active  {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;vertical-align:top;}
.detailstext3:hover {font-size:12pt;color:#000099;text-decoration:underline;text-align:left;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;vertical-align:top;}

div.center2{text-align: center;}
table {width:100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing:0px;}
.tdfam {width:120px;}
.table2 {width:83px;line-height: 0px;}
td,img {
padding:0px;margin:0px;border:none;}
.earth {width:89px;}
.tdearth {width:89px;}
.logo {display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;}
.tdemail {width:80px;}
.border {background-image: url("tinycorner.gif");
height:10px;
width:10px;}
.shuttle {background-image: url("stars2.gif");
background-repeat: repeat;}
.toprim {background-image: url("tinytop.gif");}
.leftrim {background-image: url("side.gif");}
.welcome {background-color: #000099;}
.bottomleftcorner {background-image: url("tinybottomcorner.gif");
height:10px;
width:10px;}
.bottomrim {background-image: url("bottom.gif");}
html, body {color:#ffff00;
    background-image: url("stars.gif");
    height:100%;}
    div{
        height:100%;}
```

Comment: Too many unknowns here without a runnable [mcve]

Comment: There you go. Hope that's enough for you @charlietfl

Comment: Oh deary me. what a dunce I am. The array for the preload and the array for the bpreload are the same (pics). Please delete this post if you wish